# Cerberus schema validation dependency depending of self value

Tags: python, cerberus

I know that according to the Cerberus [documentation](http://docs.python-cerberus.org/en/latest/validation-rules.html#dependencies), it is possible to define validation dependencies, according to other keys values, such as:

```
schema = {'field1': {'required': False}, 
          'field2': {'required': True, 
                     'dependencies': {'field1': ['one', 'two']}}}
```

Where `field2` is valid only if `field1` exists and has value `one` or `two`.

I would like to know if there's a way of having a validation rule that is considered depending on the value of the key itself.

Something like: `field2` needs `field1` value `False` only if `field2` value is `True`, and vice-versa.

Only one of the fields must be allowed to be `True` at a time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This could probably be solved by using `dependencies` in conjunction with `oneof` ([docs](http://docs.python-cerberus.org/en/stable/usage.html#anyof)) rule.

However, there's currently an issue which might prevent this solution from working ([ticket](https://github.com/nicolaiarocci/cerberus/issues/241)). Unfortunately I don't have the time to triage this right now, but you could give it a shot and report back here and, eventually, on the ticket itself. Good luck!

Comment: I'll give it a try and let you know. Thanks.

Comment: Yes, I think I hit the issue you mentioned. I've commented there my findings